# Thread with WriteProcessMemory

Tags: multithreading, delphi

I need some help, i'm coding a dll who modify some value from a app. but if i freeze the value app crashs (Stop Working after some time).

This is my code: 
Here i create a thread who updates the address:

```
CreateThread(nil, 0, @UpdateAddr, Pointer(nil), 0, rodaid)
```

and here is the function UpdateAddr:

```
procedure UpdateAddr;
var
  BytesWrite: DWORD;
  buf: Cardinal;
begin
  while true do
  begin
    buf := Random(38);
    WriteProcessMemory(ProcessH, SpeedAddr, addr(buf), sizeof(buf), BytesWrite);
  end;
end;
```

And here how i open the process:

`ProcessH := OpenProcess (PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, False, ProcessId);`

For any reason who i dont know the app crashs after some time when the thread are created.

Somebody can help me?

Answer (score 3):

A few problems that I can see. Including:

1. No error checking.
2. Requesting `PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS` which is more than you need.
3. The thread procedure has the wrong signature.

The last one of these would explain a crash in your app, but not the other app. The thread procedure should be:

```
function ThreadProc(lpParameter: Pointer): DWORD; stdcall;
```

Most likely the other app is crashing because you are screwing with its memory. Try removing the call to `WriteProcessMemory` and see if the other app stops crashing.

Comment: Who crash is the other app, not my app, what should i use on OpenProcess instead PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS?

Comment: Read the docs for WriteProcessMemory. The answer is there. As to why the other app crashes its clearly because you are screwing with it behind its back. Ask the developer of the app for support.

Comment: The other app are one game, and if i freeze the same address with a cheat like cheat engine the game dont crash.

Comment: Contact the developer of the game and ask for support

Comment: I'ts not possible.